# Blazor Appstate doesn't update ChildComponent

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Trying to pass down variabels with an AppState class, the components updates when the call happends in the same component but not in a childcomponent when the parrent triggers the event.

**Parent**

```
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    WikiDetailDto wikiDetail = null;

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("going in detail INIT");
        AppState.OnCurrentWikiPageChanged += StateHasChanged;
        AppState.SetCurrentWikiPage(await wikiPageService.GetDetail(Id));
        wikiDetail = AppState.CurrentWikiPage;

        Console.WriteLine("Retrieved WikiDetail!");
    }
}
```

**Child**

```
<MudDrawer Anchor="Anchor.End" Open="true">
    <MudDrawerHeader>Recommendations</MudDrawerHeader>
    @if(AppState.CurrentWikiPage != null)
    {
        @(RecommendedWikiPages = CalculateReccomendedWikis(AppState.CurrentWikiPage));
        if(RecommendedWikiPages != null)
        {
            foreach(var p in RecommendedWikiPages)
            {
                <MudCard>
                    <MudCardContent>
                        <MudText>@p.Name</MudText>

                    </MudCardContent>
                </MudCard>
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        <p>Loading...</p>
    }
```

When AppState.CurrentWikiPage gets updated, it doesn't check the if statement of the cild.
What is best practice here? I don't want to use cascading values.

**AppState**

```
public WikiDetailDto CurrentWikiPage { get; set; }
        public event Action OnCurrentWikiPageChanged;
        public void SetCurrentWikiPage(WikiDetailDto wikiPage)
        {
            CurrentWikiPage = wikiPage;
            OnCurrentWikiPageChanged?.Invoke();
        }
```

Comment: Could you not use an eventCallback?

Comment: Have a look at this project which is an implementation of what you are trying to achieve but without having to register to the Changed event for every component or property. https://github.com/dagmanolis/Blaast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your code correctly, the child component needs to register for the `OnCurrentWikiPageChanged` event.

Your child needs to look like this:

```
@implements IDisposable
..... markup code


    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        AppState.OnCurrentWikiPageChanged += StateHasChanged;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        AppState.OnCurrentWikiPageChanged -= StateHasChanged;
    }
```

Personally I would not link `StateHasChanged` directly to the event handler.  Its bad practice because `StateHasChanged` has to run the the UI context thread.  If the event caller is running on another thread, you'll get an exception.  I would stick with a standard `EventHandler`.  WASM may be single threaded now, but it may not be forever.

My Handler would look something like:

```
private void OnxxxChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
      => this.InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
```

Comment: "Its bad practice because StateHasChanged has to run the the UI context thread."  Let me put it `politely`, it's not a bad practice, it's a good practice, and it does run in the UI context thread ( at least currently). "WASM may be single threaded now, but it may not be forever." True... This is why you should call the StateHasChanged method like this: `InvokeAsync (() => StateHasChanged);`  Now you won't have any issue with the ` ExecutionContext`, no matter how many threads are being used. "I would stick with a standard EventHandler."

Comment: This is, in my opinion, the right approach, when simple things involved, but if you manage the app state, as he does, a service implementing the app state pattern and the observer pattern  is a viable choice. Sorry for my fault-finding. I won't do that again, and I'll upvote your answer ;}

Comment: @enet.  no problem, I don't take offence.   You can't guarantee all callers of event delegates always run on the UI thread - a good example being the Timer in a Server page.  Therefore I consider pointing your event handler straight at StateHasChanged is bad practice because if you do it all the time it will bite you, or someone maintaining your code, one day.  I use the `InvokeAsync code pattern myself - the belt and braces approach.  The problem here is how deep do you offer advice.  In many cases we would end up re-writing an awful lot of code for people!  :-)